# Using game engines for animations

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, blender, maya, unreal-engine4

I am new to animation world.I intend to make short animation films. I have started learning blender and have grasped modelling, rigging and rendering concepts. Recently I found out that game engines(unity, unreal) can also be used for animations.
Should i switch to 'unreal' instead as I can learn only a single tool over a period of time? 
Or would blender be enough to make good quality animation? 
Please suggest a complete animation tool for a beginner.

Comment: You can do it and afaik Unity will give you awesome results, just take a look at the blacksmith animation made in unity. That being said, why not stick to an animation-only tool? Chances are it will be much more powerful than a tool aimed at videgames or applications.

Comment: Unity is limited in what it can do in terms of animation; you're going to have a lot of headaches if you try to use it as your primary animation tool. Dedicated software like Maya or Blender are imperative if you want anything remotely complex. Regarding The Blacksmith, that animation was meant to showcase Unity's rendering capabilities, not animation prowess. Reading their [blog post](http://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/06/22/making-of-the-blacksmith-animation-camera-effects-audiovideo/), they did most of the animation with software like MotionBuilder and Maya, then imported it in via FBX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unity is capable of rendering each frame of animation in a second with almost the same quality that you would achieve with offline renting using vray or arnold for example , but using them each frame would take around 15 minutes that is
a 10 min animation needs about 3 months full time rendering

that's why I personally never use anything other than a game engine for short animation 
but I use offline rendering when one frame is intended though

Answer (score 1):

There is no point in making short films in game engines , if you want to make short film that users interacts with it somehow like a visual novel or where users input will matter in story then you should use a game engine because it is considered a game , but if you just want to make a short film then just use animation tools no need for a game engine because you don't need **real time rendering** in animations then you can get a far better rendering output by not using game engines and for animation tools there are plenty of them to use these are my personal suggestions

1. Maya+vray animation , rendering
2. mari , substance painter&designer texturing
3. Zbrush modeling